# NFC with Seeed Studio XIAO nRF52840

Tags: nfc, nrf52, nrf52840

I'm trying to use my [Seeed Studio XIAO nRF52840](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Seeed-XIAO-BLE-nRF52840-p-5201.html) like an NFC reader and like an NFC badge (not at the same time).
For this, I have bought an [NFC antenna](https://www.seeedstudio.com/NFC-Antenna-p-1805.html), I soldered the wires to the two slots provided below the card and I have tried [the official NFC example](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO-BLE-Sense-NFC-Usage/), but it returns `NFC.h: No such file or directory`.

The example of the wiki:

```cpp
#include <NFC.h>

void setup() { 
  NFC.setTXTmessage("Hello World!", "en");
  NFC.start();
}

void loop() {
}
```

But, at the top of [the wiki](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO-BLE-Sense-NFC-Usage/), It's write:

> NOTE
> The NFC function for Seeed Studio XIAO nRF52840 board is temportorily not functioning. The new wiki will be updated as soon as possible, once the new NFC library comes out.

So I did some research and couldn't find anything to solve this problem.

Have you an idea to solve my problem please ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The wiki says to use:

```
#include <NFCT.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, but it depends on the version of the card put on the IDE.The wiki version does not use the correct version (deprecated version) so I must use NFC.h